# Is it possible to set an Image as a User Profile Picture via FBML or FB PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, social-networking, fbml

I am reading the Facebook API and I am google'ing for a method or function to be able to set an image as profile picture.

I need to know if something like this is possible at all.

In the old REST Api you find a note, that it isn't possible to upload a picture into the users profile pic album. But.. is this step required for my transaction?

I would like to know which methods/function I have to take and/or an advice how to code.

(trivial workflow of app: user visits fb-app, user clicks on button, user gets an request-alert to allow action, user gets manipulated picture as own profile picture)

thanks in advance
chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but not is possible. If you take a look here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

At the "Publishing" section the `/PROFILE_ID/picture` is not writable even if you can upload a photo to an album.

Comment: Thank you for validating this. Too bad, I hoped to miss this information in the api :)